# Completely unload a ViewController at modalTransition?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle, presentviewcontroller

normally after a modal transition, the second viewController runs further "behind" the visible ViewController in the background.

Is there a possibility to completely unload the second ViewController ??
If don't want to use push, because I want an animation on the transition...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm working on a game using SpriteKit. Theres a Menu and the game itself. If the user fails at the game, he can restart it or get back to the menu. If he wants to go to the menu I make a transition to the ViewController with the menu and I don't want, that the game is in the background. The ViewController with the game should be unloaded. If the user wants to play further he can press the play button in the menu again, so theres no need to let the game run in the background. It's a waste of memory...

Comment: Put the menu controller first. Then present the game view controller. If the user fails and wants to go to the menu, dismiss the game controller and it will be destroyed.

Comment: However, I think you are optimizing prematurely, worrying yourself over something that is not really a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points:

- You are worrying about something that is not a worry. View controllers are lightweight, simple objects. The only heavyweight object is the *view*, and it is in fact removed from the interface when another view controller's view is presented in its place.
- The game does not "run in the background". If it does, you're doing it wrong. You should be detecting in `viewDidDisappear:` that your view is no longer in the interface and stopping all the activity. That's what these sorts of events are for.
- If you're still bent on making certain the view controller itself is destroyed when the game is not showing, then use a different architecture. For example, present the game controller. When the game controller is dismissed, it will be released and destroyed.